# the code cannt be run because of this error?

Tags: python, loops

I cannot run the following code it because it generates the error "break outside the loop".

```
process_queue = []

total_wtime = 0

n = int(raw_input('Enter the total no of processes or 0 to quit: '))

if n == '0': 

    print 'good bye!'
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Because you have a `break` that doesn't have anything to break from.

Just remove it.

```
process_queue = []
total_wtime = 0
n = int(raw_input('Enter the total no of processes or 0 to quit: '))

if n == 0:
    print 'good bye!'
```

Yes, as @jonrsharpe said. If you have further code, do it as:

```
if n == 0:
    print 'good bye!'
elif n == 1:
    print 'Hello!'
else:
    print 'Input not recognized'
```

Comment: but there is a code after if condition if the user input != 0 the code should continue

Comment: @user3541982 you can't `break`, though; use `else` for the other code, or perhaps put this code in a function and `return None` if the user quits.

Comment: @user3541982, Answer updated. Please see the suggested method for your new question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have updated the answer to highlight what you mean. Hopefully it is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of `break` and you should be fine:

```
if n == '0': 
    print 'good bye!'
# EOF
```

You only use `break` when you want to exit a loop.

Comment: so if the if condition satisfied i want to exit the program so what should i use instead of break ?

Comment: @user3541982 Whether the `if` is satisfied or not in your code, the program will exit afterwards. What do you want it to do?

Comment: there is an additional code that it's useless to post with the question, so the code will continue if the if condition isnt satisfied so i should write instruction to exit emmediately if the conditions satisfied

Comment: @user3541982 You want `sys.exit()`, not `break`.